# How to configure fonts on a remote X connection (XDMCP vs. ssh)?

Tags: x11, fonts, cygwin, xforwarding, xdmcp

Connecting to a remote Solaris 10 system over X11 I observe inconsistent behavior regarding the used fonts. I am connecting from a [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/) system.

When I connect using ssh forwarding like this

```
$ ssh -Y mymachine.example.org
```

fonts work as expected, i.e. the rendering is very nice and programs seem to find all kind of different fonts (e.g. gvim or emacs).

When I connect to the same machine via XDMCP (to the stock blue Solaris 10 login manager screen) and login there seems only 1 fixed size font available. An Emacs from OpenCSW even fails to execute because it can't find the fonts it needs.

It prints that it can't find a font using following specification:

```
-dt-interface user-medium-r-normal-m
```

I establish the XDMCP connection like this:

```
$ XWin -query mymachine.example.org -from mywindowsclient.example.org
```

My objective is no to get also proper fonts for the XDMCP use case.

How can I investigate this issue? Can I duplicate some configuration which is implicitly used with `ssh -Y` for the XDMCP case?

How is the font-thing usually setup during ssh-X11-forwarding?

Comment: I don't know what `XWin` does, but this seams like an issue with your environment. What X Server are you connecting to when you use the SSH approach? Is it a different one compared to the XWin use case? I'm guessing when you start the whole Cygwin thing paths are set so that all fonts can be found. If you don't it won't. Fonts are a local thing ... at least in vanilla X.

Comment: @Bananguin, when using `ssh -Y` I am doing that from inside a stock Cygwin-`xterm` which is launched when the Cygwin/X application is started. Cygwin/X calls `startxwin.exe` which it turn seems to also launch `XWin.exe`. [`XWin.exe`](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/XWin.1.html) is like a normal `X` Xserver plus some other options.

Comment: XWin is the X server that's bundled with Cygwin. There is also [XMing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) for example, a standalone X server for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe XDMCP is using the fonts local to the Solaris system. When you SSH you're using fonts that are local, since in that scenario you're the X server and the Solaris box is the X client. You can use the command `xlsfonts` to see what fonts are accessible to you on a given system.

#### EDIT #1 - Font path

You can find out your system's font path using the command `xset`.

*Example*

```
$ xset q | sed -n '/Font/,/DPM/p'
Font Path:
  catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
```

This path can include paths to local directories as well "paths" to other font servers. These will show up as port@host types of entries.

*Example*

```
$ xset +fp tcp/<IP or name of font server>:7100
```

#### References

- [Xming Fonts](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/fonts.php)

Comment: Ok, I've also tested another proprietary Windows-XDMCP client now. With that I get some fonts (all bitmaps, it seems) - at least more than one - and enough to make emacs happy. Is there an X command to investigate if that session uses some kind of X font server (address/port) or activates some other session relevant setting?

Comment: The `xset q` outputs showed no differences and a `xset fp rehash` did not help either. What makes the difference between my two setups is that with XDMCP a remote system-wide xinitrc/xdefaults file is executed after XDM login. And that mechanism sets some font related X-ressources ... You can verify this via something like `xrdb -query | grep -- -dt` and remove those entries via `xrdb -remove`. When doing  ssh X-forwarding those X-ressources are not loaded, of course.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to compare font paths via `xset q`, e.g.:

```
$ xset q
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/,built-ins
```

(a X font server (XFS) url may also be part of a font path)

If needed you can add font paths via `xset +fp path`. After manipulating font paths you have to call `xset rehash`.

The next thing is to compare the output of `xlsfonts`.

If it outputs a lot of fonts but your X programs still complain about missing fonts or simply use an ugly standard font for everything: this can be caused by font related [X-resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources) pointing to unavailable fonts.

A simple test is to start emacs - which may complain about not finding a found like:

```
-dt-interface user-medium-r-normal-m*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

You can verify if such X resources are set via something like:

```
$ xrdb -query | grep -- -dt
$ xrdb -query | grep -i font
```

If that is the case you get output like:

```
*Font:  -dt-interface user-medium-r-normal-m*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
*userFont:      -dt-interface user-medium-r-normal-m*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*:
```

You can remove those entries via `xrdb -remove` - such that the default font settings are used.

Alternatively, you can load your own font related X resources settings.

### Background

X resources are usually set via config files like:

```
/$SYS_PATH/Xresources
/$SYS_PATH/xinitrc
/$SYS_PATH/Xdefaults
$HOME/.xinitrc
$HOME/.Xresources
...
```

Or some variation on that - e.g. a lower case x.

Those files may be executed while logging in via an X display manager (XDM). When using XDMCP, XDM runs on the remote system and thus executes those files remotely.

But they are not executed when using X forwarding via `ssh`.

The obscure font name (`-dt-interface`) comes from CDE - which seems to was the default desktop environment under Solaris at some point - and they are not included with the Cygwin X server.